# Console application adding extra lines, why?

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to writing console apps.  I can't figure out why this is creating a bunch of extra lines in the console when it runs and writes messages that it's received.  I'm sure this is dumb, but I'm at a last resort as nobody on google is apparently this dumb with vb.net.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Main()
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...")
        server.Start()
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient()
        Console.WriteLine("Connected")
        Do
            stream = client.GetStream()
            Dim recvBytes(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            stream.Read(recvBytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
            Dim recvText As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes)
            Console.WriteLine(recvText)
            responses = Console.ReadLine
            If responses = "close" Then
                stream.Close()
                client.Close()
                server.Stop()
                Environment.Exit(0)
            Else
                Dim sendBytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responses)
                stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                Console.WriteLine("Message Sent")
            End If
            If client.Connected = False Then
                Console.WriteLine("Client is no longer connected")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "extra lines" mean?

Comment: Are you sure your `recvText` contains data before you call `WriteLine`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `Console.Write(recvText)` (rather than `WriteLine`)

Comment: I've managed to find a couple post on some forums in a far distant land.  It looks like it may be an issue with my buffer size argument in my stream.read() but I don't have to foggiest idea of how to find out exactly how many characters it will be receiving before the transaction takes place.  I don't really want to use a string builder of any kind because I eventually want this to receive encoded bytes that represent pixels and build them into an image.  Any ideas on how to get a good size argument for the networkstream.read(client, 0, this.one.here) method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following line is returning an empty string

```
Dim recvText As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes)
```

So before you print out the line, just verify if it is empty. The code with the modification is below:

```
Sub Main()
Do
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...")
    server.Start()
    client = server.AcceptTcpClient()
    Console.WriteLine("Connected")
    Do
        stream = client.GetStream()
        Dim recvBytes(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        stream.Read(recvBytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize)
        Dim recvText As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes)
        If recvText <> "" Then Console.WriteLine(recvText)
        responses = Console.ReadLine
        If responses = "close" Then
            stream.Close()
            client.Close()
            server.Stop()
            Environment.Exit(0)
        Else
            Dim sendBytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responses)
            stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            Console.WriteLine("Message Sent")
        End If
        If client.Connected = False Then
            Console.WriteLine("Client is no longer connected")
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe that you are probably right.  However, after implementing your suggestions and a few other things that I've thought up; I've still no luck getting rid of this giant chunk of dead space between the line written for the message and the following console.readline()     In the forms application that connects and sends messages to this console application, I've trimmed everything thoroughly and where I have a status label, I send a string reporting the send characters which are all appropriate.

Comment: Then when writing it into the console, I also trim it and recvText.Length.ToString and it ends up reporting that it has received eight thousand some odd characters in the string.

Comment: What happens if you try a different encoding? At the moment you're using ASCII, take a look at this link to test it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the encoding, Alex.  I had not even considered that.  Unfortunately, I don't believe it was the issue.  I read the entire page that you had linked to as well as the pages for the specific encodings, tried them all, and still no avail.  I'm glad you had mentioned it, though.  I'm likely to pay more attention to that in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was having was related to the receivebuffer size.  Once I had actually set it, then used string builder to build up the final string; everything worked out fine.  Thanks for all the suggestions.  These suggestions led to some very interesting and much needed reading about some things that I had not considered and, as it turns out, needed to be paying more attention to.